# Change the font color of SWT TableCursor

Tags: java, user-interface, swt

I've been messing around with SWT's TableCursor for navigating through tables using the keyboard and there is one issue I can't figure out.

The default color for a selected item seems to always be the same color even when changing the text font to something else. Is there a way to change this? I'm wanting to specifically make it look more like a mouseover like the following:

[image: TableCursor vs Mouseover]

As you can see the text is changed to a light blue and the focus ring (dotted black line) is around the cell. I would prefer if this was somewhat consistent so the two looked the same or very similar. Is this even possible using a TableCursor?

Answer (score 0):

You can try TableCursor's `setBackground (Color color)` and `setForeground (Color color)` methods to achieve what you want.